# Unable to save file without password prompt - Sublime Text 3

Tags: macos, sublimetext3, osx-elcapitan

I'm having an issue all of sudden where I am being prompted on save for the password whilst in Sublime Text 3. I am working locally with Mamp Pro. The prompt message I get on save is:

```
    Sublime Text.app wants to make changes. Type your password to allow this.
```

If I don't enter the password I get this:

```
    Unable to save ~/Sites/mywebsite/templates/fl_sidebar/index.php
    Error: administrator_copy_file(/tmp/.sublba2.tmp,
    /Users/myusername/Sites/mywebsite/templates/fl_sidebar/index.php)
    failed: AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges failed: ffff159a
```

I've never encountered this error before at all when using Sublime Text so I don't know how to fix it. I had a look at this ([How to give Sublime Text 3 write permission to files in web server's DocumentRoot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019200/how-to-give-sublime-text-3-write-permission-to-files-in-web-servers-documentroo#)) and tried the non-command line options, but it did not alter anything.

I stopped running MAMP, checked all permissions on the folder by Get Info, which stated I have read & write privilege. I restarted the Mac and opened up my local development again in sublime, made a change and was instantly asked for the password again.

I'm on OSX El Capitan Version 10.11.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you do not have write permission to that folder for your user. You can change the ownership of the folder with the following command: -

```
sudo chown -R INSERT_YOUR_USERNAME_HERE ~/Sites
```

This will recursively change the ownership of all the files in the ~/Sites folder to your user. Once you have ownership sublime should work correctly again.

Comment: I checked everything with `ls -o` and I was the owner. I think I selected a higher level folder when saving my file. I resaved the file and there was no prompt.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I didn't have ownership to the htdocs directory so I did `sudo chown -R INSERT_USERNAME /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs`

Answer (score -1):

I experienced the issue you described. I had sudo cp a file from one directory and then opened the file in Sublime. When I reviewed permissions (ls -l) it showed that the files was owned by root instead of my user account.

Therefore, every time I tried to save to the file through Sublime, I was prompted to enter my root pw.

Since I wasn't very many steps away from my initial cp, I simply recopied the file to the directory without sudo, and it fixed my problem.